# How do you toggle multiple data targets and toggles using bootstrap html data toggle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am writing code for a animated hamburger icon for the bootstrap navbar, but need to toggle both the hamburger icon and the bootstrap repsonsive navbar. So is there some code or some way to toggle both pieces of data at different ids. Also, I can't use javascript because the bootstrap navbar doesn't have the sliding animation when toggling it through javascript.

Here is the code I have already for targeting the navbar collapse feature.

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="\static\base\css\hamburgers.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="\static\base\css\navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
            <button class="hamburger hamburger--squeeze" height="15" id="hamburger" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar" data-toggle="collapse">
          <span class="hamburger-box">
            <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
          </span>
        </button>
            <a class=" navfont navbar-brand mx-auto" href="/account">Gucci Enterprises</a>
            <div class="navshow">
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <a href="/account/logout" class="navfont important">Logout</a>
                {% else %}
                    <a href="/account/login" class="navfont important" >Login</a>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
                <div class="container">
                    <div style="text-align: center">
                        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link navfont" href="/account/profile">Profile</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link navfont" href="/account/profile/edit">Edit Profile</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link navfont" href="/account/change-password">Change Password</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        {% else %}
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link navfont" href="/account/register">Register</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link navfont" href="/account/reset-password">Reset Password</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="navhide">
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <a href="/account/logout" class="navfont important">Logout</a>
                {% else %}
                    <a href="/account/login" class="navfont important">Login</a>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </nav>
        <br>
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}

    </body>
</html>
'''
```

Comment: Can you share a minimal, rendered version of your html, with the button and the sections that should be affected by the button?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".it-works">It Works</button>

<div class="collapse it-works">Yep.</div>

<div class="collapse it-works">It works.</div>
```

Add a class like `.multi-collapse` on the elements that should toggle and use `data-target=".multi-collapse"` with a class instead of an id. The [bootstrap collapse component multiple targets documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/#multiple-targets) says you can reference them using a JQuery selector and includes a working example.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to work. The data target isn't getting toggled even though I tried multiple times to make sure everything worked

Comment: I have added a minimal snippet. Works like a charm.

Comment: This is not what I need though, I need to toggle two different things, is-active and collapse, for 'hamburgers' and 'collapsibleNavbar'